# Why isn't this valid USPS tracking number validating according to their spec?

Tags: ruby, usps

I'm writing a gem to detect tracking numbers (called [tracking_number](http://github.com/jkeen/tracking_number), natch). It searches text for valid tracking number formats, and then runs those formats through the checksum calculation as specified in each respective service's spec to determine valid numbers.

The other day I mailed a letter using USPS Certified Mail, got the accompanying tracking number from USPS, and fed it into my gem and it failed the validation. I am fairly certain I am performing the calculation correctly, but have run out of ideas.

The number is validated using USS Code 128 as described in section 2.8 (page 15) of the following document: http://www.usps.com/cpim/ftp/pubs/pub109.pdf

The tracking number I got from the post office was "7196 9010 7560 0307 7385", and the code I'm using to calculate the check digit is:

```
def valid_checksum?
  # tracking number doesn't have spaces at this point
  chars = self.tracking_number.chars.to_a
  check_digit = chars.pop

  total = 0
  chars.reverse.each_with_index do |c, i|
    x = c.to_i
    x *= 3 if i.even?
    total += x
  end

  check = total % 10
  check = 10 - check unless (check.zero?)
  return true if check == check_digit.to_i
end
```

According to my calculations based on the spec provided, the last digit should be a 3 in order to be valid. However, Google's tracking number auto detection picks up the number fine as is, so I can only assume I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From my manual calculations, it should match what your code does:

```
posn: 20 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2   sum  mult
even:  7     9     9     1     7     6     0     0     7     8    54   162
 odd:     1     6     0     0     5     0     3     7     3       25    25
                                                                       ===
                                                                       187
```

Hence the check digit should be three.

If that number is valid, then they're using a *different* algorithm to the one you think they are.

I think that might be the case since, when I plug the number you gave into the USPS tracker page, I can see its entire path.

---

In fact, if you look at [publication 91](http://www.usps.com/cpim/ftp/pubs/pub91.pdf), the Confirmation Services Technical Guide, you'll see it uses two extra digits, including the `91` at the front for the tracking application ID. Applying the algorithm found in *that* publication gives us:

```
posn: 22 21 20 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2   sum  mult
even:  9     7     9     9     1     7     6     0     0     7     8    63   189
 odd:     1     1     6     0     0     5     0     3     7     3       26    26
                                                                             ===
                                                                             215
```

and that would *indeed* give you a check digit of 5. I'm not saying that's the answer but it does match with the facts and is at least a viable explanation.

Probably your best bet would be to contact USPS for the information.

Comment: I think you got it paxdiablo! awesome troubleshooting!

Comment: why would anybody have downvoted this? paxdiablo's answer is almost certainly correct.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful info. As of now this information has been moved to Section 9.0 Appendix E of  Barcode, Package, Intelligent Mail® SPECIFICATION USPS2000508 CAGE CODE 27085 which can be currently found at https://postalpro.usps.com/mnt/glusterfs/2018-02/BarcodePackageIMSpec.pdf

Answer (score 2):

I don't know Ruby, but it looks as though you're multiplying by 3 at each even number; and the way I read the spec, you sum all the even digits and multiply the sum by 3. See the worked-through example pp. 20-21.

(later)
your code may be right. this Python snippet gives 7 for their example, and 3 for yours:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
'check tracking number checksum'
import sys
def check(number = sys.argv[1:]):
 to_check = ''.join(number).replace('-', '')
 print to_check
 even = sum(map(int, to_check[-2::-2]))
 odd = sum(map(int, to_check[-3::-2]))
 print even * 3 + odd
if __name__ == '__main__':
 check(sys.argv[1:])
```

[added later]
just completing my code, for reference:

```
jcomeau@intrepid:~$ /tmp/track.py 7196 9010 7560 0307 7385
False
jcomeau@intrepid:~$ /tmp/track.py 91 7196 9010 7560 0307 7385
True
jcomeau@intrepid:~$ /tmp/track.py 71123456789123456787
True
jcomeau@intrepid:~$ cat /tmp/track.py 
#!/usr/bin/python
'check tracking number checksum'
import sys
def check(number):
 to_check = ''.join(number).replace('-', '')
 even = sum(map(int, to_check[-2::-2]))
 odd = sum(map(int, to_check[-3::-2]))
 checksum = even * 3 + odd
 checkdigit = (10 - (checksum % 10)) % 10
 return checkdigit == int(to_check[-1])
if __name__ == '__main__':
 print check(''.join(sys.argv[1:]).replace('-', ''))
```

Comment: hmm, you may be right, I also get a total of 187 which would mean a check digit of 3

Comment: I've posted it to my facebook page, hopefully one of my USPS buddies can get an answer for you. I used to be an electronics tech for the USPS years ago, but this wasn't one of the barcode specs I had to deal with.

Comment: FYI: Multiplying each number by 3 and then adding the result is the same as adding all the numbers together and then multiplying the total by 3. It's called the distributive property.

Comment: thanks jeffxl, I new that; but misread your code and thought you were mutliplying the accumulated total by 3 at each even number. I didn't go back to correct my comment because I was busy trying to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the script. Note to run it in Python 3 you must place parentheses around the argument to print since it is a function, otherwise it will raise *SyntaxError: invalid syntax*. `print (check(''.join(sys.argv[1:]).replace('-', '')))`

Comment: There are a whole lot of things wrong with my code, and even my analysis, considering the associative property of addition and multiplication, i.e., 3(a + b + c) is the same as 3a + 3b + 3c. Glad it helped you.